# Custom template filter: replace HTML element with regex filtered text (Django 2.1)

Tags: regex, django

I am building a search engine, which needs a custom filter that displays the text surrounding a keyword, like the excerpts on Google results page. I am using regex to identify the surrounding words. Here is my code for the filter:

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def show_excerpt (value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    # make the keyword put into the search engine case insensitive #
    keywords = re.compile(re.escape(search_term), re.IGNORECASE)
    # make excerpt return 300 characters before and after keyword #
    excerpt_text = '.{300}' + str(keywords) + '.{300}'
    # replace the original text with excerpt #
    excerpt = value.sub(excerpt_text, value)
    return mark_safe(excerpt)
```

Code for the search engine in view.py:

```
def query_search(request):
    articles = cross_currents.objects.all()
    search_term = ''
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['keyword']
        articles = articles.annotate(similarity=Greatest(TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term), TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term))).filter(similarity__gte=0.03).order_by('-similarity')
    context = {'articles': articles, 'search_term': search_term}
    return render(request, 'query_search.html', context)
```

HTML template (it includes a custom `highlight` filter that highlights the keyword put into search engine):

```
<ul>
{% for article in articles %}
<li><a href="{% url 'search:article_detail' article.ArticleID %}">{{ article|highlight:search_term }}</a></li>
<p> {{ article.Content|highlight:search_term|show_excerpt:search_term }} </p>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Error message: 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'sub'

I think I am doing `.sub` wrong. I just need the excerpt to replace the entire original text (the text that I am putting a filter on). The original text starts from the beginning of the data but I just want to display the data surrounding the keyword, with my `highlight` custom filter highlighting the keyword (just like on Google). Any idea?

EDIT: when I do `re.sub(excerpt_text, value)`, I get the error message sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call re.sub(), not value.sub(). You are calling sub on a SafeText object, .sub() is a regex function.

I haven't tested your code but if the remaining code is correct you should just change that line to `re.sub(excerpt_text, value)`

Comment: I changed it to that, now the error message is sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ditch regex and just do good old string slicing. Working code for the filter:

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def show_excerpt(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    #make data into string and lower#
    original_text = str(value)
    lower_original_text = original_text.lower()
    #make keyword into string and lower#
    keyword_string = str(search_term)
    lower_keyword_string = keyword_string.lower()
    #find the position of the keyword in the data#
    keyword_index = lower_original_text.find(lower_keyword_string)
    #Specify the begining and ending positions of the excerpt#
    start_index = keyword_index - 10
    end_index = keyword_index + 300
    #Define the position range of excerpt#
    excerpt = original_text[start_index:end_index]
    return mark_safe(excerpt)
```